# Is there a way I can benchmark tmpfs

Tags: ramdisk, tmpfs

I created a tmpfs which was mounted at /ramdisk using the mount command.And I tried to benchmark this tmpfs using something like this:

```
hdparm -tT /ramdisk
```

And I was told that /ramdisk is a directory.But apparently there isn't a corresponding device file under the /dev directory for the tmpfs I created.
So is there a way I can benchmark this tmpfs?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to use this tmpfs for apache2 disk cache.And I want to make sure that tmpfs is better than vps hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](http://www.gavinhollinger.com/2012/11/create-and-test-speed-of-ram-disk-on.html)

In your situation:

Test writing speed:

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/ramdisk bs=4k count=10000`

Test reading speed:

`dd if=/ramdisk of=/dev/null bs=4k count=10000`

Comment: Maybe make it more clear target is a file